# PHP send mail to 1 to 10 recepients

Tags: php

I am sure I am overlooking something here, all other mail scripts are working fine except this one. I have an HTML form which collects up to 10 email addresses. all I need to do it to iterate through them and if they are filled, send email to the recipient.

```
$email0 = 'email@email.com';
$email1 = 'some@email1.com';
$email2 = 'some@email2.com';
$email3 = 'some@email3.com';
$email4 = 'some@email4.com';
....... up to 10.

$i=1;
while($i<=10)
{
    $temp = 'email'.$i;
    if(isset($$temp) && $$temp != '')
    {               
        $subject="some subject";
        $body = "email content";

        $headers = "From: $email0 \r\n";
        $headers .= "Reply-To: $email0 \r\n";
        mail($$temp, $subject, $body, $headers);        
    }

$i++;
}
```

**...OK I just tried a different way. I stuffed all the emails in one array and iterated through it. The same result, no emails received!!!!  What am I missing ? :)**

```
$recipients = array($email1,$email2,$email3,$email4,$email5,$email6,$email7,$email8,$email9,$email10);

foreach($recipients as $value)
{
        if($value != '')
        {   
            $subject2="some subject";
            $body2 = "some content";

            $headers2 = "From: $email0 \r\n";
            $headers2 .= "Reply-To: $email0 \r\n";
            mail($value, $subject2, $body2, $headers2);
        }

}
```

**At this point I am going to post the following:**

- It just so happened that all my previous attempts started to come
  into may spam box (several hours latter!). So my suspicion seems to
  be confirmed: when on GoDaddy shared hosting do not send more than
  one email at the same time in short intervals (with the same content)
  or it will end up labeled as spam!

**SOLUTION:**

As jmbertucci in the posts below suggested, the simplest solution is to use BCC: for all the recipients in one email. Since I had to personalize each email, I noticed that if I include the unique char. into the subject line for each email, it goes through with no problem as well. So my solution is adding the recipients' name into the subject line (which makes all emails unique) but any unique string should do the same (like date() etc.)

Comment: Thats an ... interesting way to do arrays

Comment: As @AlexGittemeier alluded to, look at PHP Arrays. http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php and http://phpmaster.com/introduction-to-php-arrays/

Comment: you sure your server is configured to send mail?

Comment: ..yes, there are 2 more mail scripts in the same file and they both are going through with no issues (and they have the same headers and $from sender) Is it possible that the server (since this is a client's GoDaddy hosting) thinks that it is spam because the emails are sent too "close" to each other ?????

Comment: You're not actually sending them to `email@email.com` are you?

Comment: ..well nope, I wish it would be that simple but, no, all the emails are valid. Thanks for bringing this up though :)

Comment: ..PHPmailer is still using the mail() function and I do not need a whole class of fancy methods to send one text line :) But thanks for the suggestion, I know it work fine for more complex emails.

Comment: This doesn't solve your particular problem but why not just send 1 email with 10 BCC contacts? ... Reading through the other comments I see it was what I was worried about... spam.  10 emails in a row like that is very spammy regardless.  Let the email protocol work for you and just blast out 1 email to 10 people and not 10 emails to 1 person. =)

Comment: ...Yes, thank you. I can't believe I did not think of that! This should work.

Answer (score 0):

Did u try to check if your mail server is properly config or config it like this sample

```
// Please specify your Mail Server - Example: mail.example.com.
ini_set("SMTP","mail.example.com");

// Please specify an SMTP Number 25 and 8889 are valid SMTP Ports.
ini_set("smtp_port","25");

// Please specify the return address to use
ini_set('sendmail_from', 'example@YourDomain.com')
;
```

or check you php.ini file for this. heres a sample config.

```
[mail function]
; For Win32 only.
SMTP = localhost
smtp_port = 25

; For Win32 only.
;sendmail_from = me@example.com

; For Unix only.  You may supply arguments as well (default: "sendmail -t -i").
```

Comment: ..yes, thank you. My SMTP is is set properly and it is sending all other emails (with the same simple headers (text only) except from the code above. I just tried to make the script to send only one email from the array and one email goes through. If more than one valid email is in the array - it jams!

Comment: It must have something to do with GoDaddy settings and it is being held by some anti-spam. Any ideas how to bypass that (besides to write the code on 10 different php pages and initiate all of them since I suppose writing a class and initiating the same class 10 times will result in the same behavior ?

Comment: did u try to check if `mail()` function is executed succesfully? like adding condition to it `if(mail(param1,param2,param3,param4)){ echo 'Success'}else{ echo 'failed'}`

Comment: ..no, not this way but I inserted a simple echo $value."success"; in the foreach iteration and it reported OK. Let me try...

Comment: WOW!!!!!  This is geting interesting. I just tried your simple suggestion to test for if(mail()) and for some reason everything goes through now!!!  What the heck ?  The following code is the only thing I changed in the script:

Comment: if(mail($value, $subject2, $body2, $headers2)){ echo 'Success';}else{ echo 'failed';}

Comment: Hmmm.. no typo! This is going to bugg me whole night!!! There must be an explanation why it does not send more than one email at the time. But still - thanks :) !

Comment: Your welcome another one i see is your `$headers2` instead of `$email0` it should be $value and better get rid os spaces in betwen them of `\r\n`

Comment: ..thanks, actually the headers are correct since the email is being sent from one person to 10 recipients. It just so happened that all my previous attempts started to come into may spam box. So my suspicion seems to be confirmed: when on GoDaddy shared hosting do not send more than one email at the time in too short periods (with the same content) or it will end up labeled as spam!